# Tables overlay when displayed with a dynamic reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I am displaying a report dynamically with a dataset containing several datatables, all of the same type (same number of columns, same column types).

When displaying the report, each table of my dataset is correctly displayed.

[image: correct display]

But when I want them to appear on the printLayout, all the tables are overlaid.

[image: overlaid display]

Does somebody have an idea please ?

Comment: what happens if you increase the space between two tables? ReportViewer could have problems rendering overlapped objects (see rsOverlappingReportItems warnings when compiling solution): sometimes this error appears also if two items are too close and dynamically rendered.

Comment: very strange... simple debug: try putting a green Label between 2 Table object and see where it is rendered in printLayout. how many Table objects are you using? maybe you have reach a ReportViewer limit...

Comment: I tried adding a rectangle between my tables, and the result is very weird : all the rectangles are displaid at first (all overlaid) and then my tables on an other page, still overlaid... I don't think I've reach the report limit, because event which 2 tables, the display is wrong.